# if a is not equal to b prove that GCD$(a+\sqrt2*b, \sqrt2+1)=1$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I have this question:
given that a and b are rational numbers
if a is not equal to b: prove that $(a+b\sqrt2)/(\sqrt2+1)$ is irrational.
so I proved that $(a+b\sqrt2)$ is irrational.
but I need to prove that $GCD(a+b\sqrt2, \sqrt2+1)=1$

Comment: A $\gcd$ is only defined for integers. For real numbers see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122307/gcd-of-any-two-real-numbers), for example, as $cd$, a common divisor.

Comment: @DietrichBurde one can define $gcd$ for the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$, although I am not sure this is what OP meant to say.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I believe that they're working in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ which is a Euclidean domain so there is a GCD.

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a+b\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1} = b + (a-b)\frac{1}{\sqrt2+1}$

Comment: @KentaS Yes, but the OP first said that $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

So a divisor of $\sqrt{2}+1$ must also divide $b\sqrt{2}+b$. Since a common divisor divides both terms it divides linear combinations of them we know it must divide $b\sqrt{2}+b-(b\sqrt{2}+a)=b-a$, which is a non-zero integer since $a \neq b$, so the divisor must divide this integer. Now by inspecting $\sqrt{2}+1$ we see that the only integers that divide it are $\pm 1$ giving us a greatest common divisor $1$.